# VBA How to select each last occuring string (last item revision) in a list of grouped items

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code for what I am trying to do but not all of it yet.
What I do weekly is export a large list of part numbers that include revision letters. Here is an actual example of the list, the last letter in each case represents the revision of that item number:
DETA5121001 A

DETA5121001 B

DETA5121001 C

DETA5131002 A

DETA5131002 B

DETA5141003 D

DETA5141003 E

What I want to do, through a macro, is change the text red for each of the part numbers that occur in the list that represent an "old revision".

For example, in the above list, these would NOT turn red: (DETA5121001 C, DETA5131002 B and DETA5141003 E) because these 3 part numbers represent the last revision in each family of part numbers in the list. I want to turn all old revisions red and then delete them out. I'm just tired of manually changing text to red.

I have the macro to delete all red text, it goes like this:

```
Sub DeleteRowRedTextDec2019()

'This macro will delete a row that contains all red text in the row 12.6.19
'It will ask the user to confirm (however when we say no it deletes text anyway, separate issue)


Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim vbAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult


lRow = 20000

vbAnswer = MsgBox(lRows & " Rows with red text will be deleted.  Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "Delete Rows Macro")
  
  If vbAnswer = vbYes Then
    
    'Delete Rows
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      
  End If

For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
    
    If Cells(iCntr, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then '‘3 = Red
        Rows(iCntr).Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Should be "the last occurring part numbers" the last occurring from top to bottom, or the last alphabet letter, and they are not placed in order of their creation? Then, do all the parts name string have  11 digits?

Comment: Can you aproximate how many last revisions should exist in the range to be processed?

Comment: Do you need to first turn them red?  Or can you just delete them?

Comment: Just deleting them would work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way. The column to be processed is A:A. If something else, please adapt the code for your necessary column.

**Edited:** This code version needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':

```
Sub LastEditionBis()
 'The code needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long
 Dim arrInt, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 For i = 2 To lastR 'the code assumes that in the first row is a header
    arrInt = Split(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, " ")
    If Not dict.Exists(arrInt(0)) Then
        dict.Add arrInt(0), sh.Range("A" & i).Address(0, 0)
    Else
        dict(arrInt(0)) = sh.Range("A" & i).Address(0, 0)
    End If
 Next i
 
 If dict.count > 0 Then
    sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 3
    Dim rng As Range
    For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = sh.Range(dict.Items(i))
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, sh.Range(dict.Items(i)))
        End If
    Next i
    rng.EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 1
 End If
End Sub
```

If you don't know how to add a reference, please firstly run the next code, save the workbook and run the above code after that:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code in your first section above and it turned all part numbers red, not just the "old revisions" I should mention that yes in column A will be the part numbers but also there will be several columns of data for each part number, not just column A.

Comment: @user14302065: Firstly, I asked you some clarification questions but you did not answer them. An important one was "do all the parts name string have 11 digits"? So, is the answer at this question true? The code works based on this assumption. I would like to emphasize that VBA is case sensitive. If there are strings like "DETA5141003" and "DETa5141003", they are different. Did the code raise any error? The code philosophy is to firstly clear in red all of them and then to make black only the last revisions. What do you mean by "several columns of data for each part number"?

Comment: @user14302065: Do you mean that the code should process more then one column? Or that some other columns exist? If More columns, your question was wrongly formulated, but even if there were other versions in other columns, it should process the range in A:A column. If not something confidential, can you share the workbook you try processing? If yes, [here](https://easyupload.io/) is a free transfer site easy to be used.

Comment: Yes, sorry, there are 11 digits total. Please help, it's close. I tired to run the code again and the code worked, it changed the old revisions to red just like it should. However, when I try the code on a list that contains 350 rows of data, it turns all of the part numbers red. But, if I try this code on only 50 rows of data, it works as it should. Strange. What I meant by columns of data is that I want to change the entire row to red text, not just the part number in column A. I will look into the upload feature, have not done that before.

Comment: I will opdate the code tomorrow, to use the second suggestion. I also asked about the estimated number of last revisions, but you did not answer anything... Now it is late in my country...

Comment: Sorry, I have many things going on here but I appreciate the help. So there are 13 character strings in the part number. The first 11 characters are the part number, then there is a space, and then the revision letter. This is a total of 13 characters. There could be up to 26 revisions for a part number, basically A-Z. There will always be 13 total characters including the space between part number and revision letter. The revision letter is always the 13th spot. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @user14302065: Please, test the updated code. It now does not care of number of digits, it is enough that the version is separated by a space. Then, the code is able to choose the compact working way or the more complex one, if the string resulting from dictionary items joining exceeds 256 characters. And it also change the color of the entire involved rows... Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Thank you I tried the code and an error pops up ---> "property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object."  When I go to debug it highlights this line in your code : Set rng = sh.Range(dict.Items(i)).   Not sure how to get the code to work.

Comment: @user14302065: I cannot help if you do not share the workbook. I offered a transfer site in order to do that. The code runs well on my test workbook. I cannot know what happens in your installation... But, since the compact way is the one looking to be problematic in your case, I will eliminate it... I will do it in one, two minutes.

Comment: Ok I think I uploaded the file using the link you provided. Here it is: https://easyupload.io/5ct1q4

Comment: @user14302065: Did you test the last adapted code? I tested it on your workbook and it works very well and takes less than half of a second... Try refreshing the page (this one) and use the updated code, please. If you do not know how to add the necessary reference, run firstly the second code adding it programmatically. And send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: It's working!! That's fantastic thank you so much!

Comment: @user14302065: Glad I (finally) could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, if somebody else will search for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Answer (score 0):

I'll post some code that should help you get started once modified to suit your specific state. I use a dictionary object to hold a list of unique part numbers and the corresponding latest revision. Once the dictionary is populated, I then loop through the range again, highlighted aberrant records.

Let me know if this helps, or if you need any extra guidance.

Please note, I made one critical assumption: every record has a Revision, and it's always the last letter of the part record. If not, we can make modifications, but we'd need more info (for example, is the revision always separated by a space).

```
Sub HighlightOldRevisions()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim sPart As String
    Dim sRev As String
    
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Set sht = Worksheets("Parts")
    
    'Find the last row
    lRow = 6
    
    For i = 1 To lRow
        sPart = GetPartnumber(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        sRev = GetRevision(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        
        If oDict.exists(sPart) Then
            If oDict(sPart) < sRev Then
                oDict(sPart) = sRev
            End If
        Else
            oDict.Add sPart, sRev
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Loop through the range again, highlight old revs
    For i = 1 To lRow
        sPart = GetPartnumber(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        sRev = GetRevision(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        
        If oDict(sPart) > sRev Then
            sht.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub

Private Function GetPartnumber(sPartWithRev As String) As String
    GetPartnumber = Split(sPartWithRev, " ")(0)
End Function

Private Function GetRevision(sPartWithRev As String) As String
    GetRevision = Split(sPartWithRev, " ")(1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you , In this case there is always a space between part number and rev letter. I should also mention that yes in column A will be the part numbers but also there will be several columns of data for each part number, not just column A. Not sure if that matters. I couldn't get the code to work because the subscript was out of range, not really sure what is out of range, still looking at it now.

Comment: @user14302065 I updated the GetPartNumber and GetRevision functions to simply take the value before and after the space as the part and rev, respectively. The rest of the module should work as expected. Let me know if this helps.